# Accessing non-optimal splits in sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm using sklearn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` to produce a tree on the iris data as per the documentation

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree

I would like to access a list of sub-optimal splits at each node.  That is, to see say the top n splits, not only the top 1.
I am only interested in the top n splits with unique column names, so if n = 2, and the top splits are 
`petal_length <=2.45`,
`petal_length <= 2.3`,
`petal_width <= 1.75`
I want to see 
`petal_length <=2.45`,
`petal_width <= 1.75`.

It appears to me that I may need to write the decision tree from scratch and save them, or alternatively at each node drop the best splitting column and train a tree with one split on the rows in that node to get the next best split.  Is there any way in sklearn to access these sub-optimal splits?

Thanks in advance